# unshow null values at google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

i'm trying to invisible the null value ,
i'm using webmethod to get the values as json , 
 you will see the code down:
i'm trying this methode , but it's not working for me , i don't know why 
 the error is :

```
All series on a given axis must be of the same data type
```

if any one know where is the problem please helpe me , thanks :)
this is my code :

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var options = {
        title: 'Reparation par RSP',
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        bar: { groupWidth: "75%" },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
        colors: ['#dacfcf','#fee812','#ff7900','#ff0000','#ff0000'],
        legend: 'right',
        curveType: 'function',
        isStacked: true,

        hAxis: { format: '###' },
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 32,
        },
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ReparationParRSP.aspx/GetChartData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,
    1, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 1);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 1},
    2, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 2);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 2},
    3, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 3);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 3},
    4, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 4);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 4},
    5, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 5);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 5}
  ]);

  function getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
    return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex) || null;
  }

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_div")[0]);
            chart.draw(view, options);
           // updateChart();
        },

    });
```

i'm using webmethod to get the values as json , 
 this is where i'm getting data :

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<object> GetChartData()
    {

        string query = "select * from tblrespo";
        List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
        chartData.Add(new object[]
        {
     "Nome","0_2","2_4","4_8","8_24","+24"
        });
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-BCMH2U1\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_B2B;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        var rsp = sdr[0];

                        if (rsp.ToString()=="")
                        {
                            rsp = "aucune info";

                        }

                        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {

                                rsp, sdr[1],sdr[2],sdr[3],sdr[4],sdr[5]

                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return chartData;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data? --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(r.d));`

Comment: hii i found the error , it's where i have a null values in one bar  , i'm using sql so where a bar have all values null it's given the error , but whene i'm gettin the data from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770029/how-to-remove-zeros-present-in-the-bottom-of-google-charts) it's working even if i switch  all the values to null  , but in my case in sql is not working , i'm sorry for my english ,  hope you understand me

Comment: you found the error, so you don't need help with this question anymore?

Comment: noo i found the error but i don't know the solution to fix the error

Comment: `  {"c":[{"v":"FEB"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"JAN"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"DEC"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"NOV"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]}`  whene i have this , it's given error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is from using `arrayToDataTable` to create the data table.
when creating the column for the data table using `arrayToDataTable`,
the method looks at the data to determine what type of column should be created.
if all of the values in the column are null,
it does not know what type of column it should be,
and creates the column as `'string'` by default.

when you have a column as string, where a number column should be,
this results in the error...

```
All series on a given axis must be of the same data type
```

instead of using `arrayToDataTable`, use the following format,
and create the data table directly.
this way, the null columns are created as numbers, instead of strings.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
  "cols": [
    {"label": "Month", "type": "string"},
    {"label": "Y0", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Y1", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Y2", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Y3", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Y4", "type": "number"},
    {"label": "Y5", "type": "number"}
  ],
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"FEB"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"JAN"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"DEC"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"NOV"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]}
  ]
});
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var options = {
        title: 'Reparation par RSP',
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        bar: { groupWidth: "75%" },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
        colors: ['#dacfcf','#fee812','#ff7900','#ff0000','#ff0000'],
        legend: 'right',
        curveType: 'function',
        isStacked: true,

        hAxis: { format: '###' },
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 32,
        },
    };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"label": "Month", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "Y0", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Y1", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Y2", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Y3", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Y4", "type": "number"},
        {"label": "Y5", "type": "number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"FEB"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"JAN"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"DEC"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"NOV"},{"v":null},{"v":541438.55},{"v":442690.4},{"v":394919.81},{"v":497903.68},{"v":198755.42}]}
      ]
    });

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0,
      1, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 1);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 1},
      2, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 2);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 2},
      3, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 3);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 3},
      4, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 4);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 4},
      5, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 5);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 5}
    ]);

    function getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
      return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex) || null;
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_div")[0]);
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

in your case, it would look like the following.
just make sure keys for `cols` and `rows` are included in the json,
as shown above...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ReparationParRSP.aspx/GetChartData",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {

        // change this line
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(r.d);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0,
          1, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 1);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 1},
          2, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 2);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 2},
          3, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 3);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 3},
          4, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 4);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 4},
          5, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 5);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 5}
        ]);

        function getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
          return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex) || null;
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_div")[0]);
        chart.draw(view, options);
    },
});
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm thinking the data you're getting, looks like this is json...

```
[
  ["Nome","0_2","2_4","4_8","8_24","+24"],
  ["FEB",null,541438.55,442690.4,394919.81,497903.68],
  ["JAN",null,541438.55,442690.4,394919.81,497903.68],
  ["DEC",null,541438.55,442690.4,394919.81,497903.68],
  ["NOV",null,541438.55,442690.4,394919.81,497903.68]
]
```

as such, remove the columns headings from the server code, remove this line...

```
    chartData.Add(new object[]
    {
      "Nome","0_2","2_4","4_8","8_24","+24"
    });
```

then add the column headings on the client, in the javascript.
and use the `addRows` method, as follows...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

    var options = {
        title: 'Reparation par RSP',
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        bar: { groupWidth: "75%" },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
        colors: ['#dacfcf','#fee812','#ff7900','#ff0000','#ff0000'],
        legend: 'right',
        curveType: 'function',
        isStacked: true,

        hAxis: { format: '###' },
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 32,
        },
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ReparationParRSP.aspx/GetChartData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
              "cols": [
                {"label": "Nome", "type": "string"},
                {"label": "0_2", "type": "number"},
                {"label": "2_4", "type": "number"},
                {"label": "4_8", "type": "number"},
                {"label": "8_24", "type": "number"},
                {"label": "+24", "type": "number"},
                {"label": "Y5", "type": "number"}
              ]
            });

            data.addRows(r.d);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,
              1, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 1);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 1},
              2, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 2);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 2},
              3, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 3);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 3},
              4, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 4);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 4},
              5, {calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {return getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, 5);}, type: "string", role: "annotation" ,sourceColumn: 5}
            ]);

            function getAnnotation(dataTable, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
              return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex) || null;
            }

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_div")[0]);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: thenk you for your time, it's not showing anything , i change the line but it's not showing anything

Comment: you have to make sure the json data you're passing looks just like the above example. can you share how you are creating the json on the server?

Comment: I don't know webmethod, or how to create the structure you need on the server. instead, see __EDIT__ above...

Comment: omg thank youu so muucch broo , it's worked , thankss really thanks

Answer (score -3):

try this

```css
#Panel1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* and any other style, such as `right`, `left`, `width` and etc. */
}
```